# scanf - Multiple ints

Tags: c

In c, when I am taking inputs for multiple numbers of int, how does scanf know which number to store in which variable and when to stop?

```
 printf("Enter the numbers from 1 - 16 in any order: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f,&g,&h,&i,&j,&k,&l,&m,&n,&o,&p);
```

when the user inputs for example - `16 3 2 13 5 10 11 8 9 6 7 12 4 15 14 1`

it stores 16 to variable a, which is what i want. but how does scanf know that 16 will be stored to variable a and not 163. Because as far as I know, scanf ignores white/blank space, so shouldn't it be storing all the digits to variable a?

can someone please explain?

Comment: A whitespace character is not a number. Is it?

Comment: and you probably did not check the return value (which should stress that the scanf did not do what you expected)

Comment: **Lets Solve the Problem**: If you want to get the Numbers Try to get the Numbers in Char Array and then iterate it One by One to check if Number, and at Last Perform your Action..

Comment: To the question how does scanf (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf) parses the info according to format you can have a look at the source code of scanf  https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.30/scanf_8c_source.html and then you will want to know more about variadic function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_C and you are off to a wonderful journey

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` most certainly does *not* ignore whitespace!

It's an occasionally surprising fact that the scanf format `%d` does *not* just mean "scan and convert an integer".  What it actually means is "skip any whitespace, then scan and convert an integer".

So your scanf format

```
"%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"
```

is equivalent to what you might have thought you needed

```
"%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d"
```

to do.

And the whitespace that `scanf` skips is arbitrary.  It can be spaces, tabs, newlines, and other whitespace characters, and there can be multiple of them, in any combination.  (That's true both for the implicit whitespace skipping which format specifiers like `%d` automatically do, and also the explicit whitespace skipping that happens if you include any whitespace characters — blank, tab, newline — in the format string.)

The automatic, implicit skipping of leading whitespace happens for most of `scanf`'s input specifiers.  But there are three exceptions: leading whitespace is *not* skipped for the `%c`, `%[…]` or `%n` specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that `scanf()` ignores white/blank space; it splits the input string by those delimiters.
This way

```
16 3 2 13 5 10 11 8 9 6 7 12 4 15 14 1
```

turns into

```
16
3
2
13
5
10
11
8
9
6
7
12
4
15
14
1
```

which it later iterates through all of them and puts each of them in the desired variable by the order they were put when calling `scanf()`.

Answer (score -2):

scanf will store value in order like it will store 1st input value (%d) into first variable used in C and same as it will store 2nd value into 2nd variable

Comment: This is not what OP is asking about. They seem aware of the order of the reads into variables. Instead they are confused by the treatment of whitespaces as explained by the other answers.